# Print index number of dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to pull out strictly the index number from the following dictionary:

```
data = {0: {'GAME_ID': '0021600457', 'TEAM_ID': 1610612744}, 1: {'GAME_ID': 
'0021600457', 'TEAM_ID': 1610612744}, 2: {'GAME_ID': '0021600457', 'TEAM_ID': 
1610612744}
```

I'd like to be able to do something like

```
print(data[x])
```

And have it return:

```
0
```

I'm sure this is something simple that I'm overlooking?

Comment: What is X here ?please elaborate question

Comment: X just represented the unknown.  I updated this so that the dictionary is called "data".  Can I type some command along side "data" so that it will print the first index number?

Comment: Please give an example value of `x` and what the output would be.

Comment: I don't have an example for this specific need.

If I wanted to return the first GAME_ID, I could type print(data[0]['GAME_ID]) and get '0021600457'

Put what do I need to type to have it return the "0", which represents the first record?

Comment: Dictionaries don't have a concept of "first".

Comment: @gommb  Sorry... accidentally hit enter too early... I just updated my comment above.

Comment: The keys of a dictionary are not indices, not necessarily integers, and not stored in a predictable order. Therefore `x` is the what you're (incorrectly) calling the index—and you already have its value.

Comment: @MarkRansom So is there no way to reference the actual values of "0", "1", "2" in this example?

Comment: @GeorgeRodman: `x` *is* the actual value. You don't need to look it up, you *have* it. You'd do a lookup to find what `x` (the key) maps to (the value).

Comment: You can get a list of the indexes with `data.keys()` but they won't be in any particular order. If they look like they're in order, that's an accident.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have mixed up index numbers with keys.
Dictionaries are formed like such:

`{key: value}`

`data.keys()` will return a list of keys.
In your case:

```
data.keys()
[0,1,2]
```

From there, you can call the first item, which is 0 (First item in a list is 0, and then progresses by one).

```
data.keys()[0]
0
```

If you are looking for a specific key by the predefined values, then try:

```
x = 'GAME_ID'
y = '0021600457'

for index_num, sub_dict in data.items():
    for eachsub_keys in sub_dict.keys():
        if eachsub_keys == x:
            print(index_num)

for index_num, sub_dict in data.items():
    for eachsub_values in sub_dict.values():
        if eachsub_values == y:
            print(index_num)

Output:
0
1
2

0
1
2
```

**Note:** python3 no longer uses .iteritems()

By the way, you are missing a curly brace at the end.  It should be like this:

`data = {0: {'GAME_ID': '0021600457', 'TEAM_ID': '1610612744'}, 1: {'GAME_ID': 
'0021600457', 'TEAM_ID': '1610612744'}, 2: {'GAME_ID': '0021600457', 'TEAM_ID': 
'1610612744'}}`

Assuming that you wanted consistency, I've added the missing quotes as well.

Comment: Ah.  OK.  Yes, my terminology was incorrect.  Thank you!!

Comment: @GeorgeRodman I have expanded my answer to include predefined searches.

Answer (score 1):

Some more info on dictionary operations in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict).

This what you want?:

```
data = {0: {'GAME_ID': '0021600457', 'TEAM_ID': 1610612744},
        1: {'GAME_ID': '0021600457', 'TEAM_ID': 1610612744},
        2: {'GAME_ID': '0021600457', 'TEAM_ID': 1610612744}}

for key in data:
    print (key)

# Outputs:
0
1
2
```

If you are trying to iterate over the values:

```
data = {0: {'GAME_ID': '0021600457', 'TEAM_ID': 1610612744},
        1: {'GAME_ID': '0021600457', 'TEAM_ID': 1610612744},
        2: {'GAME_ID': '0021600457', 'TEAM_ID': 1610612744}}

for value in data.values():
    print (value)

# or

for key in data:
    print (data[key])
```

Answer (score -1):

Could you clarify where you are getting 'x' from?  If you want to print keys, you could just do

```
for i in dict:
    print(i)
```

Comment: If you don't have the rep to comment, don't put them into an "answer" like this.