# Best method to get "sub" values from Python dictionary?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

What is the best way to read values from a Python dict?

- Complete function, and dict code included below

**Context**

After doing some research it appears as though the get() method -should- do the trick.
However, my code below only ever seems to return "None" for the `"title"` key.

I highly suspect that I need to go into the sub-dictionary/key-value-pairs, but I'm not *quite* sure what that would look like.

This solution is -close- to what I'm trying to do, except I want the strings, not the indexes.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47107021/6779209

This is another similar question which seems to come close:
[Accessing values from Python sub-dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50492713/accessing-values-from-python-sub-dictionary)
When I try to add  `title = [user['title'] for user in data]` to my function I get an error: `TypeError: string indices must be integers`

I can certainly try adding a `for` loop but I question whether or not that is overkill.

This is the specific line where I am trying to print additional values.
`print(f"{user} is streaming {data.get('title')}")`

**My Python Code**

```
#-
# Check status against JSON file
# This also set the keys on a per-user basis
#
def processJSON():
    with open('channel_data.json', 'r') as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
    channel_json = json.loads("".join(lines))
    data = {}
    for element in channel_json['data']:
        data[element['user_login']] = element
        
#-
# Determine if the user is online or not
    for user in streamers:
        if user in data.keys():
            print(f"{user} is streaming {data.get('title')}")
        else:
            print(f"{user} is offline :(")
    
#   print( json.dumps(data, indent=3) )

# End processJSON()

processJSON()
```

**Sample Dictionary (created using json.dumps() for debugging)**

```
  {
   "dutchf0x": {
      "user_login": "dutchf0x",
      "user_name": "DuctchF0x",
      "game_name": "Monopoly Plus",
      "title": "nobody loses friendships with this game",
      "viewer_count": 24773,
      "started_at": "2021-07-07T16:59:08Z",
      "thumbnail_url": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_philza-{width}x{height}.jpg",
      "is_mature": false
   },
   "libertyranger": {
      "user_login": "libertyranger",
      "user_name": "libertyranger",
      "game_name": "Science \\u0026 Technology",
      "title": "Streaming UFO Cam - Background Audio is Copyright FREE, 1920s through 1960s Sci-Fi Radio Theater",
      "viewer_count": 1,
      "started_at": "2021-07-06T12:52:25Z",
      "thumbnail_url": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_libertyranger-{width}x{height}.jpg",
      "is_mature": false
   }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you use `data[user].get('title')`?

Comment: Eyyyyy!!! That did it :D

I figured it was something really stupid like this hahah :D +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case `data` has two layers. you first need to get your streamer.

Try:

```
data[user]['title']
```

Comment: Yeah the comment that @not_speshal gave me worked :)
Being new to Python (and JSON processing) I tried a bunch of iterations of trying to get into that second layer.  Somehow I missed these :)

Comment: This kind of stuff happens. If this answer worked, please mark it as correct.

Comment: Your solution works as well. - Marked accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

The best idiomatic way to do this is:

```
data.get(user, {}).get("title")
```

This will return `None` if either the user or the user's `title` is missing. The first `get` returns the nested dictionary or an empty dictionary if `user` is missing, the second `get` will return the value at the `title` key, or `None` (the default return value for `get` if the item is missing) if there is no `title` key.

Note that if you use the `data[user]` syntax, if `user` does not exist in your dictionary it will throw an Exception. This may be preferred, but if not, use `get`.

Comment: Thank you for elaborating :)
In my particular instance (Twitch API queries) either all of the data will exist (user is online) or not exist (everything NULL).  But for other use-cases I can see this being really handy to have.

Answer (score 0):

Using the suggestions from @not-spesuhl, and @conmak this updated version gets me moving forward :)

```
def processJSON():
    with open('channel_data.json', 'r') as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
    channel_json = json.loads("".join(lines))
    data = {}
    for element in channel_json['data']:
        data[element['user_login']] = element
        
#-
# Determine if the user is online or not
    for user in streamers:
        if user in data.keys():
            print(f"{user} is streaming {data[user].get('title')}")
            print( data.get("title") )
        else:
            print(f"{user} is offline :(")
    
#   print( json.dumps(data, indent=3) )

# End processJSON()

processJSON()
```